# jQuery sum of newly created input values

Tags: jquery

Im trying to calculate `sum` of created input value but somehow its not giving right result (for example: if I create 2 input with value 1 it shows 3)

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" class="new">new</a>
<a href="#" class="report">report</a>
<div class="container"></div>
<p>total:<span></span></p>
```

**JS:**

```
var total = 0;

$('.new').click(function(){
    $("div").append('<input type="text" name="amount"/>');
});

$('input').live('keyup', function(){
    $('.container input').each(function(){
        total += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    $('span').html(total);
});

$('.report').live('click', function(){
    $('.container input').each(function(){
        alert('input: '+$(this).val());
    });
});
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Wn2cs/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`live()` has been deprecated, and you should be using `on()`.

The issue is the global var `total`, and on each keyup you keep adding to that global, it never resets. It should be defined in the event handler instead :

```
$('.container').on('keyup', 'input', function(){
    var total = 0;
    $('.container input').each(function(){
        total += parseInt($(this).val(),10);
    });
    $('span').html(total||0); // avoids NaN
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Wn2cs/5/)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('input').live('keyup', function(){
    var total = 0;

    $('.container input').each(function(){
        var value = parseInt($(this).val());
        total += value;
    });
    $('span').html(total);
});

$('.report').live('click', function(){
   alert($('.container input').length);
});
```

Comment: That will give the wrong answer if any input contains a different value than `1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="input-container">
    <a href="#" class="new">New</a>
    <a href="#" class="report">Report</a>

    <div id="inputs-area"></div>

    <p>Total:<span id="total">0</span></p>
</div>

var InputCalculator = (function ($) {

    /* Static Content */
    var _$container = $('#input-container');
    var _$inputsArea = $('#inputs-area');
    var _$total = $('#total');

    /* Helpers */
    var _getTotal = function () {
        var total = 0;

        _$inputsArea.find('input').each(function () {
            var currentValue = parseInt(this.value, 10);

            if (!isNaN(currentValue)) {
                total += currentValue;
            }
        });

        return total;
    };

    /* Events */
    var _createReportEvent = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        alert('Total: ' + _getTotal());
    };

    var _createInputEvent = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        _$inputsArea.append($('<input>', { type: 'text' }));
    };

    var _recalculateEvent = function() {
        _$total.text(_getTotal());
    };

    var _bindEvents = function () {
        _$container.on('click', 'a.report', _createReportEvent);
        _$container.on('click', 'a.new', _createInputEvent);
        _$inputsArea.on('keyup', 'input', _recalculateEvent);
    };

    var init = function () {
        _bindEvents();
    };

    return {
        init: init
    };

})(jQuery);

InputCalculator.init();
```